# Комплекс вопросов : Timber в RxJava, DataBase в RxJava, присвоение RecyclerViewAdapter DataBase объектам в RxJava

Tags: java, android

Цель: Конвертировать список Api объектов в roomDataBase объекты и присваивать RecyclerViewAdapter уже roomDataBase объектам. И все это делать ,  не в основном потоке с помощью RxJava.

Timber почему то не выводит в логи "DbArticle insert" в SportNewsFragment поэтому не понимаю вставились у меня объекты в DB или нет.

Вообщем, туплю 4ый день.
Спасибо. 
Прилагаю SportNewsFragment , RecyclerViewAdapter, Converter, Api class - Article, DataBase classes

```
public class SportNewsFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    Converter converter;
    ArticleDao articleDao;
    CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sportnews, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
        Timber.d("onViewCreated");
        apiClient.getArticleList("us", "sports")
                .map(sportNews -> sportNews.articles)
                .map(articleList -> converter.convert(articleList))
                .map(dbArticles -> articleDao.insert(dbArticles))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext (don->Timber.d("DbArticle inserted"));
        ????????????????????????????????????????????????????



    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        compositeDisposable.dispose();
    }
}

//    public void showError(String errorMessage) {
//        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        Timber.d(errorMessage);
//    }


//        apiClient.getArticleList("us", "sports").enqueue(new Callback<SportNews>() {
//            @Override
//            public void onResponse(Call<SportNews> call, Response<SportNews> response) {
//                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
//                    SportNews responseBody = response.body();
//                    if (responseBody != null) {
//                        List<Article> articlesFromApi = responseBody.articles;
//
//
//                        adapter.setArticleList(articlesFromApi);
//                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                    } else {
//                        showError("responseBody == null ");
//                    }
//                } else {
//                    showError("no Response " + response.code());
//                }
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onFailure(Call<SportNews> call, Throwable t) {
//                showError(t.getMessage());
//            }
//        });
//    }
```

```js
@Entity
public class DbArticle {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String author;
    public String title;
    public String description;
    public String url;
    public String urlToImage;
    public String publishedAt;
}


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
@Database(version = 2, entities = {DbArticle.class}, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract public ArticleDao articleDao();
}
```

```js
public class Converter {

    public static List<DbArticle> convert(List<Article> articleList) {
        List<DbArticle> dbArticleList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Article article : articleList) {
            DbArticle dbArticle = new DbArticle();
            dbArticle.author = article.author;
            dbArticle.description = article.description;
            dbArticle.publishedAt = article.publishedAt;
            dbArticle.title = article.title;
            dbArticle.url = article.url;
            dbArticle.urlToImage = article.urlToImage;
            dbArticleList.add(dbArticle);
        }
        return dbArticleList;
    }
}
```

```js
public class Article {

    @SerializedName("source")
    public Source source;
    @SerializedName("author")
    public String author;
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;
    @SerializedName("description")
    public String description;
    @SerializedName("url")
    public String url;
    @SerializedName("urlToImage")
    public String urlToImage;
    @SerializedName("publishedAt")
    public String publishedAt;

}
```

```js
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setArticleList(List<Article> articleList) {
        this.articleList = articleList;
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView tvTitle, tvAuthor, tvDescription;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            tvDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAuthor);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Article article = articleList.get(position);
        holder.tvDescription.setText(article.description);
        holder.tvAuthor.setText(article.author);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(article.title);
        GlideApp
                .with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(article.urlToImage)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articleList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока формулировал вопрос , частично нашел ответ - в RecyclerViewAdapter я принимаю Api class Article , а нужно DbArticle , т.к. я уже сделал insert.

Но Timber в doOnNext все равно не выводит лог.

Comment: Для уточнения вопроса - дополните вопрос, а не пишите ответ на свой же вопрос.